# Finding general expression of series expansion $A^{-1} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n a_n x^n$, $A = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, power-series, formal-power-series

Let
\begin{align}
&A^{-1} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n a_n x^n \\
&A = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n
\end{align}
Using the relation $A^{-1} A =1$, I want to find the general expression for $a_n$.

My assumption and initial conditions are given as follows with $a_0=1, a_1=1$.

With this I find explicitly, $a_2= \frac{1}{2}$, $a_3 = \frac{1}{4}$, $a_4 = \frac{1}{8}$, $a_5=0, \cdots$. How I can set the general expression for $a_n$?

---

After seeing the comment from @metamorphy,  I want additionally impose all odd powers vanishes except $a_3$. i.e., $a_{2n+1}=0$ for $n>1$. In this case, is this fix the uniqueness?

Additionally I relax the positiveness condition for $a_n$.

Comment: The solution is not unique. Take any $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^{2n+1}$ with $c_n\geqslant 0$ and $c_0=1$, and let $A$ be the series for $e^{f(x)}$. (Say, $f(x)=x$ results in $a_n=1/n!$, etc.) Isn't there something else missing?

Comment: @metamorphy, how about setting all odd powers except $a_3$ be vanishes? In this case, is still $a_n$ not unique?

Comment: In case it’s helpful, $A^{-1}=f(-x)$, where $f(x)=A$.

Comment: Now there's **no** solution (with $a_n\geqslant0$ for even $n$). Should I give it as an answer?

Comment: I gave my solution before I read about the condition that $a_n\ge0$. But this was the crux: you can write $f(x)=f_0(x)+f_1(x)$ as a sum of even/odd parts, then the odd part $f_1(x)$ determines two solutions for the even part $f_0(x)=\pm\sqrt{1+f_1(x)^2}$ by expanding the binomial series.

Comment: Someone should correct me if I'm wrong, but using the [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) it seems that$$A^{-1} A = \sum_{i=0}^\infty (-1)^i a_i x^i \cdot \sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j x^j = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{\ell=0}^k (-1)^\ell a_\ell a_{k-\ell} x^k = 1 \\ \implies \begin{cases}a_0 = \pm1 \\ a_n=0&\text{for }n>0\end{cases}$$

Comment: @user170231 How are you getting $a_n=0$ for $n>0$?

Comment: @runway44 I would think that series = constant means all non-constant terms in the series drop out, but maybe there is some detail I'm overlooking.

Comment: @user170231 Obviously series = constant implies nonconstant terms vanish, but whence the assumption series = constant?

Comment: Is OP not solving for $a_n$ such that $A^{-1}A=1$? @metamorphy I don't follow. That choice of $a_n$ makes $A=\frac4{x-2}$ and $A^{-1}=\frac4{x+2}$, but $A^{-1}A\neq1$ (as long as $|x|<2$).

Comment: @user170231 Yes, OP is solving for $a_n$ such that $A(x)A(-x)=1$. And?

Comment: I have the same opinion Mr.user170231. Using the formula of the product of series this is what we get!

Comment: @runway44 I see I made the mistake of jumping to $a_n=0$, when it should be$$\sum_{\ell=0}^k (-1)^\ell a_\ell a_{k-\ell}=0$$for $k>0$, but I still don't understand what you're getting at. If $A^{-1}A=1$ and both $A^{-1}$ and $A$ are series, then $A^{-1}A$ is a series, and surely this series = constant?

Comment: @user170231 You said it seems $a_n=0$ for $n>0$. I asked how you got $a_n=0$ for $n>0$. You responded by saying series = constant implies all nonconstant terms vanish. Hopefully you can see from my perspective why when you said "series = constant," I assumed the series you were talking about was $A(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you are looking for is an $f$ so that
$$
f(x)f(-x)=1\tag1
$$
and
$$
f(0)=1\tag2
$$
and so that the odd part is
$$
\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}2=x+\frac{x^3}4\tag3
$$
Solving $(3)$ for $f(-x)$ in terms of $f(x)$ and multiplying by $f(x)$ gives
$$
f(x)^2-2\left(x+\frac{x^3}4\right)f(x)-1=0\tag4
$$
Applying the quadratic formula to $(4)$ and remembering $(2)$ gives
$$
f(x)=\left(x+\frac{x^3}4\right)+\sqrt{\left(x+\frac{x^3}4\right)^2+1}\tag5
$$
At the moment, I don't see an easy expression for the coefficients of the Taylor series of $\sqrt{\left(x+\frac{x^3}4\right)^2+1}$ .

However, you say that you deduced that $a_3=\frac14$. Given your initial conditions, you can set $a_3$ to anything and get a solution (just replace the $\frac{x^3}4$ term in $(4)$ and $(5)$).

Comment: It is necessary that you relaxed the $a_n\ge0$ condition, since $a_6=-\frac1{32}$.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is not unique, but as some in the comments have pointed out the even coefficients in the expansion of A(x) are determined (up to a sign) by the odd coefficients, which are arbitrary.

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be respectively the even and odd parts of $A(x)$. Then

$$1 = A(x)A(-x) = f(x)^2 - g(x)^2$$

So $f(x) = \pm \sqrt{1+g(x)^2}$ and $A(x) = g(x) \pm \sqrt{1+g(x)^2}$ for any odd function $g(x)$. To expand in series you can apply the fractional binomial theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from @robjohn's answer

$$\sqrt{1+\left(x+\frac{x^3}4\right)^2}=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{2^{2n-1}}\,x^{2n}$$ where the $a_n$ form the (bizarre) sequence
$$\{1,1,-1,1,0,-3,8,-11,0,44,-126,177,34,-892,2498,-3355,-1598,20732,-55374,\cdots\}$$ which does not seem to appear anywhere.